# There are 2 records in the database but only 1 entry is listed

Tags: php, while-loop

There are 2 records in the database but only 1 entry is listed

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tarlalar ORDER BY tarla_id ASC");
while ($tarla_row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `fetch_array` alone isn't a function that I'd know of. It's either a method of mysqli class OR it's mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: please insert your code as text, not as link to an external image. When you select all code and hit `Ctrl+K` it will be formatted as code.

Comment: <div>
<?php

 $query = query("SELECT * FROM tarlalar ORDER BY tarla_id ASC");
 while ($tarla_row = fetch_array($query)){

 ?>
<div>
...
</div>

<?php } ?>
</div>

Comment: The original MySQL extension is deprecated(PHP 5.5.x) and removed in PHP7. Instead consider using the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: sorry, without the full (real) code we can't help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4Nl0-Ub5amppXQP4NjZ4BPt7YXfMxHI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wkzEa9Eq93crQq6LZ7rgH__Z_qQo9rVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in here. as part of the question. And not an image of parts of the (old) code.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite hard to understand your coding. As I am assuming that your code must not be producing any fatal error, I would say that you have not posted the whole coding of your page.

I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
$dbconn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$rst = $dbconn->query("SELECT * FROM tarlalar ORDER BY tarla_id ASC");
for($i = 0; $i < $rst->num_rows; $i++){
    $row = $rst->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print row['tarla_adi'];
}
$dbconn->close();
```

Hope, this will help.